# RSelenium: Entering search term - trouble with css selector

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to trigger a search on this [site](https://www.cec.ro/sucursale). First, I want to enter a search term, then click the search button. I am able to to do the second step, however I am unfortunately unable to access the search field. Below my attempt.

Start RSelenium

```
link_to_page<-"https://www.cec.ro/sucursale"

library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 483L, verbose = F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to site, and wait

remDr$navigate(link_to_page)
Sys.sleep(5)

#Search for element by its id

remDr$findElement(using="css", "#edit-localitate--_jjPr3WukFY")

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
         Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
         class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
         Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

There is apparently something wrong with the css selector. I checked, it's not nested in an iframe or so, but mabe it's related to the 'form' element it is nested in? Grateful for any hint. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is *`NoSuchElement`* which indicates an element could not be located on the page using the given search parameter

The second part of the *classname* i.e. `_jjPr3WukFY` is dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

You need to consider any of the other attributes which is ***static*** in nature. Example:

```
remDr$findElement(using="css", "button[id^edit-localitate]")
```

or

```
remDr$findElement(using="xpath", "//button[starts-with(@id, 'edit-localitate')]")
```